# Integral from 0 to infinity involving integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following:

$$\int_0^\infty\ x e^{-x} dx$$

How would I use integration of parts when I have the natural e in my problem?

Edit:Solved by the following...

I set $u=x$, $dv=e^{-x}$, $du=1dx$, and $v=-e^{-x}$

By parts, I came up with

$$-xe^{-x} - \int -e^{-x} dx$$

From this I came up with $-xe^{-x} - e^{-x}$ from $0$ to $b$, which led to: $(-be^{-b} +e^{-b}) - (0-1)$.

Second $b$ term went to zero, used L'hopital's rule on the first one.

Integral equals $1$.

Apologies for not including more info in my original post, and I appreciate any and all feedback.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Claude for the edit on the exponent

Comment: Well you have to choose the parts.  What do want to integrate and what to you want to differentiate?

Comment: Did you try anything when you know you have to integrate by parts?

Comment: Hi and welcome! I see you are still learning some of the ropes concerning this site, so here's another: questions lacking [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) may become closed, especially questions of the form "Here's my problem" and not much else. For example, have you tried taking $x$ or $e^{-x}$ as your $u$ or $v$? If so, please try adding this in, as it'll also help us help you.

Comment: Hi @SimplyBeautifulArt I have updated with my approach. Would you tell me if this is how you would approach? Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: hi @StubbornAtom , i Updated my approach. thank you for your feedback and let me know if you would have taken a similar route.

Comment: @saulspatz you are right. I provided some clarity in my post now. Thanks for the feedback. Do you agree with the route I took?

Comment: Thanks. By the way, you can use `-` followed by a space if you want to do bullet points, perhaps instead of those `//`.

Comment: I have also [edit]ed it to use MathJax. Note that `{...}` acts like the parentheses in e^(-x) for the code, so you don't end up with things like $e^-x$ instead of $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Now it looks correct to me.  Of course, if you just want to check that you got the right answer, you can plug it into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+xe%5E(-x)+from+0+to+infinity)

Comment: Just for the answer, your integral is $\Gamma(2)$, which equals $1$.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using integration by parts

$$
\int_0^\infty x e^{-x} \, dx = \left[ x (-e^{-x}) \right]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty 1 (-e^{-x}) \, dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \, dx = 1
$$

#### Using another technique that can sometimes be useful

First let
$$
f(t) := \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} \, dx = \frac{1}{t}
$$
Then,
$$
\int_0^\infty x e^{-xt} \, dx = -f'(t) = \frac{1}{t^2}
$$
and setting $t=1$ gives our integral,
$$
\int_0^\infty x e^{-x} \, dx = \frac{1}{1^2} = 1.
$$